# Active member in (tagged) union

Tags: c, unions

I've got a union I'm running a program verification software over, and would like to say something about which member is active. So I've tried writing it as a tagged union:

```
struct my_struct {
    enum my_tag {v1, v2};
    struct{
        enum my_tag tag;
        union {
            type1 v1;
            type2 v2;
        }value;
    }my_taggedunion; 
};
```

and am running a program verification software on it. I would like to add the requirement that, if `my_taggedunion.tag == v1` then the active member in the union should be `v1`.

I'm trying to write something like "if `my_taggedunion.tag == v1` then `my_taggedunion.active_member == v1`. What is the correct syntax for the conclusion?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. There is no field `my_taggedunion.active_member`. What exactly do you want to do when `my_taggedunion.tag == v1`?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on your program verification software?

Comment: Exactly, I'm asking how I can specify what the active member is

Comment: As in, is saying that the tag is equal to `v1` enough to say that the active member is v1?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "say".

Comment: Well, you are setting it. If  that is the semantics of your program then yes.

Comment: How are you testing?

Comment: The active member is the one that was last assigned to. So your software should track assignments.

Answer (score 3):

There is no notion of an "active member" as far as C is concerned.  Note that according to the ANSI C standard:

> If a pointer to a union is cast to the type of a pointer to a member,
>   the result refers to that member.

(see 3.5.2.1 of X3.159-1989 and A8.3 of Kernighan & Ritchie)

You have to keep track of the relevant part of the union yourself, which in your case you are doing through `my_tag`.